# Dojox Grid pass two fields to formatter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dojo, dojox.grid

I created a dojox.Grid successfully, but in one case I need to pass two fields to a formatter function instead of just one.
For instance:

```
   {
        field: 'id',
        name: 'Id',
        formatter: formatterFunction,
    },
```

I need to pass to formatterFunction() both 'id' and 'name' for instance. How can I do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I know this was already mentioned in the IRC channel, but I'm answering here so others are aware, and also to address your further question that I'm not sure anyone answered.

> New in 1.4  If you set the value of the field to "_item", then your formatter will be called with the entire item from the store - instead of just one field value

This makes it possible to do what you want using a formatter as well.

http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html#usage

In the simplest case, without setting the grid's formatterScope, the grid's store can be accessed from within formatters via `this.grid.store`, e.g.:

```
function fmtItem(value) {
  var store = this.grid.store;
  return store.getValue(value, 'id') + ': ' + store.getValue(value, 'name');
}
```

Here's a really simple example of the above formatter in action:

http://jsbin.com/upico4/edit

There's also an example of this in one of the test pages, which creates an object to hold and scope the formatters:

http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/tests/test_grid_formatters.html

Answer (score 3):

As from dojo 1.4 you can also get multiple fields from a store. Should look something like:

```
    var layout = [{
        rows: [
          {name: 'Title', fields:['Title', 'url'], formatter:formatLink}
        ]}]

    function formatLink(value){
        return '<a href="'+value[1]+'">'+value[0]+'</a>';
    }
```

That uses the value from the field "url" to point your link at and the displayed title is filled with the data from "Title" field in your store.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to format and maybe not use get instead?
When you use a formatter the *only* value that is passed to the function is the value that field represents.

However, if you were to use get instead, you could use the item to access the other values. (However then you will lose sorting).

So for your column have

```
   {
        field: 'id',
        name: 'Id',
        get: getFunction
    },
```

Then have

```
getFunction: function(index,row) {
    return row.id + row.name;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function formatterFunction(val, rowIdx, cell){

  var name=this.name,
  field=this.field;

}
```